# Child component removed by parent still gets store change event

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

tl;dr: same issue as described by mridgway here: [isMounted is not enough to know if you can setState](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2787#issuecomment-101068292)

I have a components hierarchy like this:

```
PhasesList
- Phase
  - PhaseHeader
- Phase
  - PhaseHeader
```

And a PhaseStore, which maintains a list of phases, along with their details.

In all three components, I listen for PhaseStore changes and update state (rerender) based on changes. For example if user changes a phase name in PhaseHeader, I trigger action, store updates and emits change event. That change event is propagated to PhaseList, Phase and PhaseHeader which are rendered with actual name value.

There is an problematic case where I can remove a phase. This action is handled in PhaseStore, where the phase is removed from list and change event is emitted (as in other cases). This event is handled by all components, from top to bottom (since all listen to store change).

So, in PhasesList, new set of phases is rendered, without the one removed. However, that removed phase component still receives the change event, as well as the PhaseHeader does.

In these two components, in phase change handler I use setState. The message I'm getting is this:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

I found out people used isMounted to check that component is still in DOM. This method is now deprecated.

How could I solve this in proper, flux way? What's the issue with design of my components and their intercommunication?

Comment: You would probably need to make sure to disable your phase change handler within componentWillUnmount - i'm not sure whether this would work or be enough in your specific case.

Comment: Exactly, in `componentWillUnmount` you should cleanup/unsubscribe all things that you did in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Yes, I'm removing the handler it in all components, that register for that event in `componentWillUnmount`. This doesn't help. When the store change event is triggered, all three handlers are looped through. In first handler (PhaseList), new phases are set. Then another two handlers are called (Phase and PhaseHeader), where the removed phase is gone already.

Comment: Same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121231/stores-change-listeners-not-getting-removed-on-componentwillunmount Resolved by wrapping the callback method in a function. This for some reason ensured your callback is removed from the Eventmitter.

Comment: Just came across the announcement about isMounted deprecation. Very nice explanation and reasoning I agree with. The edge case which I have is still not covered though - having a reference to the callback in flux itself (as a registered change handler in child component of the parent that's being removed...) https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you should just use [React Redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux) that generates container components.  It is already heavily optimized, will work faster than manual code using `setState()`, and specifically has a protection for the case you mentioned.

Otherwise you can do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(this.handleChange.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribe();
  this.unsubscribe = null;
}

handleChange() {
  if (!this.unsubscribe) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, this is working well and for now will suffice. I'm about to use Redux on current project, so that I can compare both. So far Redux seems very promising and easier than "vanilla" flux pattern I used before.

Comment: I had a similar problem when using Alt, and using this approach (invoking the unsubscribed function from the `listen` method instead of `unlisten`) solved it.

Answer (score 2):

The very natural way is to subscribe to events in `componentDidMount` and unsubscribe in `componentWillUnmount`.

Another thing is, instead of listening to changes on various component levels, I'd better do that on a root component level only, PhasesList in your case. It will pass all the changes down via props, allowing React to determine which child requires an update.

Comment: Passing the props down the hierarchy is what I wanted to avoid. I started with React components, without flux, then added flux to reduce the callbacks and props passing. Basically, the idea was to let each component get whatever data it needs from stores. Is that a no-no in flux pattern?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's about Flux. It's more about React, unidirectional data flow and keeping as many components stateless as possible. Passing the props down the hierarchy - it's very React way. They even got [stateless functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) since 0.14. Very simple, very easy to test.
All your data management should really go to some higher level root components only.

Comment: Thanks Grigory. I still need to update from 0.13.3, but I like the stateless components shortcut they introduced. Based on what you say it looks like I have to set some boundary on where to pass the data and where to listen for events, based on the reusability criteria. Going from one extreme (everything passed down) to the other (listeners everywhere) is probably not correct on either side.