# ComponentwillMount is called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm my `componentWillMount()` is called everytime I switch routes.

Is there other way how to handle changes in store's state?

When I use the two functions for the first time it's ok but, when I switch routes and go back and try to use them again I get this message

`warning.js:45 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.`

**InventoryList.js**

```
import React from "react";
import InventoryItem from "../components/InventoryItem";
import InventoryItemStore from "../stores/InventoryItemStore";
import { Link } from "react-router";

export default class InventoryList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: InventoryItemStore.getAll(),
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        InventoryItemStore.on("change", () => {
            this.setState({
                items: InventoryItemStore.getAll()
            });
        });
    }

    render(...);
}
```

**InventoryStore.js**

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";

class InventoryItemStore extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.items = [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "first item",
                stockQuantity: 10
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "second item",
                stockQuantity: 5
            }
        ];
    }

    getAll() {
        return this.items;
    }

    // Adds new item to the inventory store
    addItem( title, stockQuantity ) {
        const id = Date.now();
        this.items.push({
            id,
            title, // We don't have to do title: title because of ES6... Thx ES6
            stockQuantity
        });

        this.emit("change");
    }


    /**
     * Lower the stock quantity of certain item
     * @param  {integer} id
     * @param  {integer} stockQuantity
     */
    lowerQuantity( id, orderQuantity ) {

        this.items.map((item) => {

            if ( item.id == id ) {
                item.stockQuantity = item.stockQuantity - orderQuantity;
            }

        });

        this.emit("change");

    }


    handleActions( action ) {

        switch( action.type ) {
            case "ADD_ITEM": {
                const { title, stockQuantity } = action;
                this.addItem( title, stockQuantity );
            }
            case "LOWER_QUANTITY": {
                const { id, orderQuantity } = action;
                this.lowerQuantity( id, orderQuantity );
            }
        }

    }

}

const inventoryItemStore = new InventoryItemStore;

dispatcher.register(inventoryItemStore.handleActions.bind(inventoryItemStore));

export default inventoryItemStore;
```

Comment: Would you try to write some codes which unbind 'change' event from InventoryItemStore at componentWillUnmount?

When a react-router is changed, your components will unmounted and then remounted. If you don't unbind 'change' event from store, finally two events remain. It causes event listener be called twice.

Comment: thank you for your comment, you are right, but I don't know what code to put in ``componentWillUnmount`` to actually remove the change event listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component will get unmounted every time you change route, and a new one will be mounted when you change back.

Since you're registering a eventhandler with `InventoryItemStore.on` but never unregistering it you're left with two components listening to `change` and the one that isn't mounted throws the error.

Use `componentWillUnmount` to un-register your component so it doesn't hang around like a ghost and haunt you when you navigate back.

See [React lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) for more life-cycle hooks.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I couldn't figure out what is the exact use of ``componentWillUnmount`` but now I see :)

Comment: but do you think you could point out, where should I put ``componentWillUnmount``?

Comment: At InventoryList.js

Comment: I'm sorry I asked wrong. How to actually unmount the event. I placed the ``componentWillUnmount`` but I don't know how to unbind the 'change' eventListener

Comment: @JakubKohout You use `removeListener`, it's demonstrated in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34200536/957731) answer.

Comment: Took some searching to find that and it might actually even be a duplicate of this question.